# automatically set vars' names python

Tags: python, variables, loops

I'm working on python program and i want something like this:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    var(a+str(i)) = input()
    #do something
```

So that variables are a1,a2,a3,etc.
Can this be done, and how?

Comment: Why do you want that? Use a dict instead! And why was this question upvoted? For what reason?

Comment: You should get acquainted with the idea of zero-based numbering. The need to go through contortions like `range(1,n+1)` instead of `range(n)` should alert you to the fact that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I need 'i' on multiple places, so I'd have to put (i+1) everywhere else. So range(1,n+1) makes the code shorter in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do that, trust me. You want to use a dictionary

```
vars = {}
for i in range(1,n+1):
    vars[i] = input()
    #do something
```

or, since all the numbers are sequential in your special case, a list:

```
vars = [None]  #  initialize vars[0] with None
for i in range(n):
    vars.append(input())
    #do something
```

Now you can access your variables like `vars[2]`, `vars[5]` etc.

Comment: (Of course, `vars` is a terrible name for a variable - you should use a meaningful name instead. This is just meant as an example.)